# Knockout, previous value of select / dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to know what the previous value is from a Dropdown list.

In the following html I can set the Options and the currently selected.

```
    <select data-bind="options: group_128,
                       optionsText: 'description',
                       value: selectedgroup_128,
                       event: { change: selectionChanged_group_128 }">
    </select>
```

in the Javascript / viewModel I do :

```
            selectionChanged_group_128 = function (data, event) {
            self.addItemClicked2(self.selectedgroup_128, event)
        };
```

At this point I want to know what the previous selected item was to send it to the addItemClicked2.

Answer (score 4):

You could subscribe to the observable to get the value before it changed:

```
self.selectedgroup_128.subscribe(function(oldValue) {
    self.selectedgroup_128.previousValue = oldvalue;
}, null, "beforeChange");
```

Now you can get the previous value like this:

```
self.selectedgroup_128.previousValue
```

Comment: Very elgegant, thanx, although, i can have a whole bunch of (generated) Groups, and therefore i go for the other solution of aquinas wich generates less jscript in my case :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just change your model to store the new value as previous value?

http://jsfiddle.net/uLeDP/

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.group_128 = ko.observable([{description:"first"},{description:"second"}]);
    this.selectedgroup_128 = ko.observable("first");
    this.prevgroup_128 = null;
    this.selectionChanged_group_128 = function(val) {        
        alert("Now I'm " + this.selectedgroup_128().description + " but I was " + this.prevgroup_128);
        this.prevgroup_128 = this.selectedgroup_128().description;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution i will implement :)